# WPF DataGrid Parent Child Data

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, parent-child

I'm new to WPF/C#/NET but I have been learning by way of coding some small exercises.

Anyway, I'm stuck. I have seached on here and google and can't find the answer or maybe more correctly can't find an answer I can make sense of.

My problem is this... using the Entity Framework I have two tables. One for Employee details and one for Company details. Employees work for 0 or 1 Company's.

I would like to, via WPF/XAML, define a datagrid to navigate Employees. But within each employee row I would like to show the name of the Company they work for (if there is a relationship) or "Unemployed" in the cases where there is no related Company record.

I have not given details of the tables as it really doesnt matter - the problem is displaying concatentated information from parent/child relationships in a single datagrid.

I dont know what the best approach to this kind of problem is, I'm assuming WPF/DataGrid, so I would really appreciate help on how to go about doing it, the binding (assuming WPF) or even an example of the WPF/XAML

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this - one way you might try is to create a View Model that encapsulates the data you want to display - e.g.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    private readonly Employee _employee;

    public EmployeeViewModel(Employee employee)
    {
        _employee = employee;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _employee.Name; } }
    public string CompanyName { get { return _employee.Company == null ? "Unemployed" : _employee.Company.CompanyName; } }
}
```

Then, given an `IEnumerable<Employee>` you can project your employee data into this view model and set it as the ItemsSource of your DataGrid - e.g.

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = GetEmployeesFromDatabase();    
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = employees.Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel(x));
```

You would normally set the ItemsSource via a xaml binding here rather than setting it directly in code but that would involve the use of a parent ViewModel set as the DataContext of the View and I'm trying to keep things simple.

Another way to accomplish this with a DataGrid would be to forgo the use of a View Model, bind directly to an `IEnumerable<Employee>` collection and set the column bindings explicitly - e.g.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" Binding="{Binding Company.Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Note that with the second example, you won't get "Unemployed" appearing in the Company Name column where there is no associated company for an employee.

EDIT: To clarify the point about setting the items source for your Grid from a property on a 'main' view model bound to the View, you might create a ViewModel class that represents the whole of the current view. e.g.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Employee> _employees;

    public MainViewModel(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
    {
        _employees = employees;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
    }
}
```

You'd set this as the DataContext for the Window / UserControl.

e.g. in simple cases you could do this in the constructor for your Window (although calls to the database should really be asynchronous for WPF apps where possible).

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new MainViewModel(GetAllEmployees());
 }
```

Then you can set up the binding on your Grid like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" ...
```

The data context for the main window is then used for all the child controls contained therein except where you explicitly set the DataContext on a child control. This technique becomes useful where you have more complex ViewModels with many properties and commands. If you are interested in finding out more you should take a look at the MVVM pattern and either or both of the Prism / Caliburn frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Steve.
A couple of questions. In my code I'm not setting the grid's ItemsSource like your example. I simply have ItemsSource="{Binding}" and then I set the grids.DataContext to my ObjectSet<Employee> on the Window_Loaded event.
Now when I try your second example Company.Name results in nothing being displayed for the Company name. If I just have Company then I get the row id for the correct Company record. Also in my designer Company.Name results in the .Name bit being in red not blue.
What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Hi Chris, your ItemsSource="{Binding}" after setting the DataContext of the grid is achieving the same result as binding the whole view to a higher level view model with an Employees property on it, so no problems there. {Binding Company.Name} assumes that you have a property on your company object called Name - if this is not the case you'll need to substitute Company.Name for Company.CompanyName or whatever the required property on the Company object is.

Comment: Steve, the Company table does have a column of Name. the Company entity has an attribute of Name. But the only thing I'm binding is the collection of Employees. I think I'm missing a fundemental step here...

Comment: You should be able to bind an Employees collection in this way. I'm assuming the employee class has a property called Company? If so then the {Binding Company.Name} property path syntax will navigate to the Company property of the Employee for each row and then get the Name property of the Company. A good way to see if you have any binding errors is to run in Debug mode and take a look at the Output window in Visual Studio (Debug -> Windows -> Output) - any binding errors will normally appear there.

Comment: One more thing, if you are using an older version of Entity Framework (anything before V4.0) then the Company property is not lazy loaded by default - you may need to use an "Include" statement in your EF query. This is generally a good idea anyway to avoid the Select n+1 problem.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Ok, I got there in the end on that one. The reason what i thought should work wasnt working turned out to be a case sensitive issue. The following works for me now: Binding="{Binding ecustomer.Name}"

One last question. In your OP - can you explain the bit you were avoiding in order to keep things simple? I'd like to understand all the options for this type of situation. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it to work. I added some explanatory text about binding a single ViewModel to the root of the main view.

Comment: Thank you Steve, hugely appreciated.